# imaplib STORE failed - Mailbox has read-only access. Cannot Delete Yahoo Email

Tags: python, email, imap, imaplib

trying to delete emails in my yahoo account using imaplib. i'm new to python, figured out most of the code but unable to find anything that works relating to this error.

```
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_server)
imap.login(email_address, password)

imap.select("Learn", readonly=False)
con = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.mail.yahoo.com',993)

con.login(email_address, password)
con.select('Learn',readonly=False)
imap.select('"Learn"', "(UNSEEN)")
for i in '1':
    typ, msg_data = imap.fetch('1', '(RFC822)')
    for response_part in msg_data:
        if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
            msg = email.message_from_bytes(response_part[1])
            for header in [  'from' ]:
                print('%-8s: %s' % (header.upper(), msg[header]))
                imap.store(i, "+FLAGS", "\\Deleted")
                #tried commented codes below and same error
                #imap.expunge()
                #result, data = imap.uid('STORE', str(i)  , '+FLAGS', '(\\Deleted)')
                #imap.uid('STORE', i, '+X-GM-LABELS', '\\Trash')

con.close()
con.logout()
```

i get the error below
STORE command error: BAD [b'[CANNOT] STORE failed - Mailbox has read-only access']

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is there in fact a mailbox called 'Learn' on Yahoo, and are you supposed to have write access to that?

Comment: And what is this? `imap.select('"Learn"', "(UNSEEN)")`   Select doesn’t take that parameter.  Did you mean to do a search?  It is probably being treated as readonly=True, as all non empty strings are true.  Remove that line.

Comment: Learn is a folder I just created to test this script. Already tried running it on the inbox, still get the same error. I’d I remove ‘unseen’ it would look at all messages, read and unread correct? I want to be able to delete unread messages only.

Comment: Select does not do that, it does not take search terms. You would have to use the search function. selects only function is to choose a mailbox.  Please check the document again. Search is right above select so maybe you mixed them up?

Answer (score 0):

```
imap.select('"Learn"', "(UNSEEN)")
```

Select does not take a search criterion. The second parameter is “readonly”, so this is the same as:

```
imap.select('"Learn"', readonly="(UNSEEN)")
```

Which as a non-empty string is the same as:

```
imap.select('"Learn"', readonly=True)
```

Which is why you can’t make any changes to that mailbox.  Delete the second parameter:

```
imap.select('"Learn"')
```

You appear to be wanting to do a search for unseen messages.  Use `search` for this.